# XSD How to require an element inside an optional element

Tags: xml, xsd

I have the following schema snippet:

```
              <xs:element name="JobRecord" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="JobControlCode">
                  <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                      <xs:maxLength value="40" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                  </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="JobRecordStatusDate">
                  <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:dateTime">
                    </xs:restriction>
                  </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
```

The JobRecord node is optional, but if it is present I need to require that the JobControlCode & JobRecordStatusDate are present. The above XSD is not achieving this. Thanks for any assistance with this.

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An xs:element is optional if its `minOccurs="0"` and its `maxOccurs="1"`.

If you force the use of other xs:elements if the above described is used (as a tag in your xml files) one possible way would be to make them to child elements of said optional element and to set their own min- and maxOccurs both to 1.
An example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="myRootElement">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="myOptionalElem" minOccurs="0">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="myFirstRequiredEl" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="mySecondRequiredEl" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

As you can see in this example optional element is the one called myOptionalElem.
It's minOccurs attribute is set to 0 times by me.
You may have noticed I didn't write down `maxOccurs="1"`. That's because it's not necessary to note that.
Every xs:element has implicitly a min and max occurence of `1` if not defined differently by the programmer.

That means the xs:element myOptionalElem is indeed optional because it is possible for it to not occure once. In that case its child elements can't appear,too (in the corresponding xml file as xml tags).

If the xs:element myOptionalElem does appear (as a tag in the xml) its child elements have to appear in the xml file,too, because their min and max Occurs are all `1` by default!

You can find another example at this xml schema tutorial from w3schools:
http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_example.asp

hope I could be of healp, frosty

Comment: Thanks frosty, I appreciate the assistance. It seems the problem was with the validator somewhere as the snippet above is actually correct. I tested against the freeformatter.com and found it was working as expected. Thanks again.